# Factory Method Design Pattern -PHP

Tags: php, design-patterns, factory

I am reading about factory design pattern, this pattern comes in 3 forms, simple factory, factory method and abstract factory.

what I understand, that's simple factory is not a design pattern, it just a type of encapsulate the object creation code in conjunction with if/switch statement or direct loading for the classes with exception if the class not exist!.

When I tried to move to factory method I can't find a clear enough example to defer it from simple factory.

could you guys give an example that's explain the factory method and how its defer from simple factory?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Simple Factory**

A *simple* class with different methods (or one with a `switch`) that is fully implemented with the creation logic. In PHP it can look like:

```
class AnimalFactory
{
    public function CreateAnimal($type)
    {
        if ($type == 'Dog') {
            return new Dog();
        } else {
            return new Cat();
        }
    }
}
```

If tommorow you'll have a new animal to support, you will have to change this class implementation.
There are no subclasses here - this class knows everything about `Animal` creation.

**Factory Method**

Is what you use when you have a class that does some proccessing with `Animal` but doesn't know how or which `Animal` to create yet, therfore would like to have subclasses that will determine that. So we create a factory method that the sucblasses can override.

```
abstract Class MyAnimalProcess
{
    abstract function CreateAnimal();

    public function Process()
    {
        $animal = $this->CreateAnimal();
        ...
        ...
    }
}

class DogProcess extends MyAnimalProcess
{
    function CreateAnimal()
    {
        return new Dog();
    }
}
```

So, here you can have and abstract class that does something with an `Animal`, but let the subclasses of it determine which `Animal` it will be.

**Abstract Factory**

Take the factory method one step forward, and delegates the creation to another class - "the factory" class.
So it uses composition rather than inheritance.

```
abstract class AnimalFactory
{
    public abstract function CreatePet();
    public abstract function CreateWildAnimal();
}

class DogAnimalFactory extends AnimalFactory
{
    public function CreatePet()
    {
        return new Dog();
    }

    public function CreateWildAnimal()
    {
        return new AfricanWildDog();
    }
}

class CatAnimalFactory extends AnimalFactory
{
    public function CreatePet()
    {
        return new Cat();
    }

    public function CreateWildAnimal()
    {
        return new Tiger();
    }
}

class MyAnimalProcess
{
    function __construct($animalFactory) {
        $this->factory = $animalFactory;
    }

    public function ProcessPet()
    {
        $animal = $this->factory->CreatePet();
        ...
        ...
    }

    public function ProcessWild()
    {
        $animal = $this->factory->CreateWild();
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe this will help, to make it more clear,
Abstract Factory is collection of the Factory Methods.

examples from real life:
[Factory Method](https://github.com/dstar55/100-words-design-patterns-java#FactoryMethod) - plasticine/mold
[Abstract Factory](https://github.com/dstar55/100-words-design-patterns-java#AbstractFactory) - cards factory

Comment: How is the particular factory mehtod useful when you have to check for the type in the subclass to create instance ?

Comment: These links above redirected to spam/scam or harmful website. Don't click.

Comment: @TommyDo try now, domain not in use any more, now you have link to github repo